# Does BoUML' State Machine generator handle exit and entry into a compound state correctly?

Tags: uml, code-generation, state-machine

Consider the following `History` state machine:

[image]

When the code below is run ...

```
  machine.create();
  machine.check();
  machine.stop();
```

`machine` generates the following output:

```
01 DEBUG : current state is now .History.Outer
02 DEBUG : execute entry behavior of .History.Outer
03 Entry behavior Outer
04 DEBUG : current state is now .History.Outer.Inner
05 DEBUG : execute entry behavior of .History.Outer.Inner
06 Entry behavior Inner
07 DEBUG : fire trigger check
08 DEBUG : execute exit behavior of .History.Outer
09 Exit behavior Outer
10 DEBUG : current state is now .History
11 DEBUG : current state is now .History.Outer
12 DEBUG : fire trigger stop
13 DEBUG : execute exit behavior of .History.Outer
14 Exit behavior Outer
15 DEBUG : current state is now .History
16 DEBUG : final state reached
```

I see two issues with this output.First, according to the UML specification, paragraph **14.2.3.4.6 Exiting a State**

> When exiting from a composite State, exit commences with the innermost State in the active state configuration. This means that exit Behaviors are executed in sequence starting with the innermost active State.

But after trigger `check` is fired (line `07`), only `Outer`'s state exit behavior is executed (lines `08` and `09`).  Exit behaviour of `Inner` never executes.

Second, according to paragraph **14.2.3.4.4 State History**

> Deep history ( deepHistory ) represents the full state configuration of the most recent visit to the containing Region. The effect is the same as if the Transition terminating on the deepHistory Pseudostate had, instead, terminated on the innermost State of the preserved state configuration, including execution of all entry Behaviors encountered along the way.

Thus I would expect to see a copy of lines `02-06` after line `11`.

Am I right?

Answer (score 3):

The state machine generator is just a demonstrator of a class generator/model transformation. It only manages trivial state machine, as you can see after you applied it there is no inner class generated to support the inner state, and nothing is done for historic state nor region, pseudo state ...

It is a *plug-out*, it is not part of the modeler (BoUML executable), so you are free to improve or completely rewrite it for your own. This is the *raison d'être* of the *plug-outs*, to allow you to not be limited by the features I deliver.

Comment: @zer0hedge difficult to know, all depends on you, try/do and you will know ;-). Just notice a plug-out can be implemented in Java and/or C++ independently of the language(s) it may be manages, and the right way to do is to define them into BoUML from the special *plug-out* 'empty' part of the distribution. See [documentation](https://www.bouml.fr/doc/index_plugout.html). The model for BoUML of state machine generator is also part of the distribution

Comment: Under which license do you distribute the state machine generator source code? I couldn't find any and it means that it is under exclusive copyright, so I can't change it!

Comment: the licencing is indicated in [legal mentions](https://bouml.fr/legal-mentions.html) : `The code generated for the plug-outs is under the term of the GNU General Public License`, so you can change it, the result being still under the GPL. It is the same for the *plug-out* themselves